# AAR Android embed dependency

Tags: android, embed, arr

I would like to create an AAR that has an one of its dependencies embedded.

The dependency is not going to be deployed to a public maven repo, hence why I want it to be embedded.

I don't want to manually copy the dependency to the libs directory as it is in a privately accessible maven repo.

Comment: What form does the dependency take?  Is it a jar, an aar?